# link with escape-sequence html

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

i have a problem for link with escape...

```
 var linkregion= '<a href=\"http://www.example.com/Reg_'+numeroReg+'\" target=\"blank\">'+'Description of Reg: '+numeroReg+'</a>';
 document.getElementById('linkreg').innerHTML = linkregion;


 <span id="linkreg"></span>
```

`numeroReg` is a number

But when the document is ready, at the firs of link there are: `">`
See the image:

http://i58.tinypic.com/2enm62f.png

i hope can you help me :(

Thanks

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/cq18kndg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not escape the double quotes, because the string is in single quotes.

```
 var linkregion = '<a href="http://www.example.com/Reg_' + numeroReg + '" target="blank">Description of Reg: ' + numeroReg + '</a>';
```

Comment: It does no harm to escape double quotes in a single quoted string in JS. `'Hello\"' === 'Hello"'`

Comment: You are right, escaping the double quotes was the problem indeed.. Thanks.

Comment: The quotes are not the problem — http://jsfiddle.net/cq18kndg/ — the code in the question doesn't have a problem.